# jquery click() on a link

Tags: jquery, html, triggers, click

I'm trying to trigger a click on a link when a page loads via ajax call, I tried all methods I found, but I can't manage to do that.

Considering that the link on which I want to trigger the click is given by this code

```
<a href="download.php?file=cloud/index.html" target="_blank" id="cliccami">Click here</a>
```

Here are the codes that I tried

```
<script> $("#cliccami").trigger("click"); </script>
<script> $("#cliccami")[0].click(); </script>
<script> window.open($("#cliccami").attr("href"), "_blank"); </script>
```

Both script and element are in the page loaded via ajax call.
Could anyone help me to find out what's the matter?

Comment: Where's the script in relation to the element, did you include jQuery, are you triggering the click after the page is loaded with that ajax call etc....

Comment: Thanks for your comment. They're both in the page loaded via ajax call, I included jquery, and I'm triggering the click immediately after the page is loaded with ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT, I think this is what you're looking for:

html:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" id="cliccami">Click here</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#cliccami').click(function(e) {
        window.open($(this).attr('href'));
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#cliccami').click();
});
```

In my example (JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qw9BW/) `#cliccami`'s click event is captured, alerted, then stopped. then a $.click() is ran on page load to force the click event to happen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code actually works, but I can't figure out how to open a specific link basing on it

Comment: I'll update my code/jsfiddle with a working version.

Comment: @Angelo updated ... keep in mind this might cause issues with popup blockers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a *ready* function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#cliccami").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your code, but it does not work anyway

Comment: Strange... Works well in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andreyvk/u4uFz/) though. See if your jQuery is loaded properly.

Comment: If you are trying to open a blank page on page load, maybe you could try setting href to _about:blank_ or some valid URL... Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. If I try to trigger an alert, it actually works, but I can't make it open an URL.